# how to use leaflet markercluster spiderfied event

Tags: javascript, leaflet, leaflet.markercluster

I want to listen to spiderfied and unspiderfied events on the cluster group. These events are described [here](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster#additional-markerclustergroup-events).
I have the following code and I am not able to listen to the events.Plese help.

```
var markerGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();
//adding markers to markerGroup
// ...

markerGroup.on('spiderfied', function (a) {
    // a.layer is actually a cluster
    console.log('cluster ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length);
});
markerGroup.on('clusterspiderfied', function (a) {
   // a.layer is actually a cluster
   console.log('cluster ' + a.layer.getAllChildMarkers().length);
});
```

edit: added [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pj744o3/1/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You correctly attach a listener to the Marker Cluster Group `"spiderfied"` event, but there is no `layer` attribute to the event argument.

As stated in the documentation:

> Contains `cluster` and `markers` attributes

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/BgzBDbLY7oPEW98jaNiX?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Please note that the SO way to thank people is also to _accept_ the answer that helped you solve your problem. When you get enough _reputation_, you will also get the ability to _upvote_.